# pnp update existing out of the box field

Tags: pnp, pnp-provision, office-dev-pnp

I have an xml document which contains a list of content types and fields. One currently contains a field that is out of the box, which I am wanting to change the default value of within this xml document. 
Would this be where I set my custom fields and have a sort of 'update field' or would this be in the list where my content type is placed where it lists the fields and add the default section there.
I am new to pnp so not sure how to do this.